# Github actions add JSON as a secrets error (in local environment)

Tags: json, google-drive-api, github-actions

I'm currently doing some experiments about github actions in local environment and being stuck with an error.

What I want to do is

- Access Google Drive in Github actions runner's environment
- Test above action workflow with secret variable in local environment

To achieve above, I used [this](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/google-drive-simple-download#How-to-create-a-project,-service-account-and-generate-authentication-key) action workflow to access google drive and [act library](https://github.com/nektos/act) for local experiment as below.

- test.yml

```yaml
- name: Download Google Docs from Google Drive
  uses: k0staa/download-gdrive-file-action@v1
  with:
    service-account-auth-json: ${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_AUTH_JSON }}
    download-file-name: [target_file_name]
    export-media-type: text/plain
    download-to: [destination_path]
```

- my.secrets

```
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_AUTH_JSON = [my_config_json]
```

- 'act' command

```bash
act -j [job_name] --container-architecture linux/amd64 --secret-file my.secrets
```

Given all the process above, It is impossible to run action flow with an error as below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "/scripts/download_file.py", line 51, in <module>
|     service_account_info = json.loads(os.getenv("SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_JSON"))
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
|     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
|     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
|     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
| json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I tried json configuration file as a base64 format and just plain text format, but neither works.

Since I'm not an owner of the github repo, it is inevitable to conduct experiment in local environment.
Hope anyone can help please.

Tried different format of configuration json file, ends up with same error.

Comment: The env var `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_JSON` is different than `SERVICE_ACCOUNT_AUTH_JSON`. Please make sure you're using the right one. Apart from that, you can pass the secret from the command line instead of a file just to verify that it works or not.

Comment: Also, remove the surrounding spaces of `=` in your secrets file i.e. `k = v` => `k=v`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! But how can I pass the secrets from the command line? you mean just exporting as a env variable?

Comment: With `-s` flag. See https://github.com/nektos/act?tab=readme-ov-file#secrets.